# ExtJS 3, get data from across pages in a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Im using grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections(); but it returns the data only from the page Im currently on. I want the data that I select on the other pages as well. The rows remain selected but Im not getting the data in the function.

Any tips? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getSelections()` will return the data held within the `Ext.data.Store` pertaining to the rows you clicked. Whenever you change pages, the store gets reloaded with the new data. ExtJs may remember which rows had been selected, it doesn't (and shouldn't) remember the data from all the pages.

What you should do is to have a separate array/object (that you could attach to the grid) in which you would keep all the selected row data. This would need to be refreshed on any selection change.

Comment: The way the code is wired, I am not able to create any events like the one you suggested. Is there another way to do it. I though getSelections() would always return all the selected elements but that doesnt work

Comment: can you post some code? i'd like to know why you can't create an object that contains the selection...

Comment: from what I understood, the store is local to the paging. so If i do a get store on a page, I get whatever is selected on that page and not the previous one. I will post some code shortly, sorry for the delay.